# Concurrent users db timeout issue while making db insert after api call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

The case is that ;

I have `ServiceA` which responds with `AResponse` after 5000ms per request.

I also have `ServiceB` that calls `ServiceA` (which makes the api like call). And according to `AResponse` inserts data into db (currently hsql).

I have 2 db connection pool limit. And 30000ms connection timeout default. I don't want to change these values.

So When trying to 100 users at the same time calling `serviceB.getAndSave()` method. It gives timeout after 30 seconds to users.

```java
// ServiceA method of getting response
public AResponse getData(param){
  try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          return new AResponse("SUCCESS");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      }
}
```

```java
// ServiceB class has annotation @Transactional
// In ServiceB inserts data to db depends on serviceA's AResponse.
public getAndSave(){
    AResponse aresponse = serviceA.getData(param);
    MyData myData = new MyData(aresponse)
    myRepository.save(myData);
}
```

So how can I handle this situation without dirty data and handle that timeout pitfall. By the way all my data must be persisted correctly.